# Pegar URL direta de uma imagem da minha aplicação ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer uma API para retornar a URL de uma lista de imagens mas não sei como fazer isso.

Achei coisas com `server.mapPatch` mas esses retornam o endereço físico do arquivo.

Queria retornar a URL tipo assim:

```
www.meusite.com.br/conteudo/categoria/foto.jpg
```

Fiz assim mas me retorna o caminho físico, queria a minha `URL`

```
public JsonResult Fotos()
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/imagens/categoria"));
    var lista = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        lista.Add(item.FullName);
    }
    return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Consegui fazer desse jeito mas ficou feião, parece gambiarra :C

```
var dominio = "http://localhost:53592";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/imagens/categoria"));
var lista = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
{
    lista.Add(dominio + "/Content/imagens/categoria/" + item.Name);
}
return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria desta maneira amigo:

```
string dominio = Path.Combine(Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority);

DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/img/icons/led"));
List<string> lista = dirInfo.GetFiles().Select(x => Path.Combine(dominio + "\\Content\\imagens\\categoria\\", x.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: isso ai que eu queria, valeu